# Como esperar uma bool ficar true?

Tags: c#, wpf

Tenho esse método `async` que atualmente espera um tempo declarado por mim. O programa primeiro reinicia a `boolean` de resultado e depois envia comandos para uma serial que depois de um certo tempo devolve no meu programa os resultados naquela mesma `boolean`.

Mas é evidentemente uma má prática eu precisar definir o tempo "`hard coded`" por que por algum motivo pode chegar a resposta mais rápido do que o esperado, ou ainda, mais lento. Abaixo uma amostra de como é o código:

```
public async Task StartNewTest(TestType test)
{
   double time = 0;
   switch(test)
   {
     case TestType.Alerts:
        time = 20000;
        AlertOK = false;
        SendSerial("A");
     case TestType.Lights:
        time = 18000;
        LightsOK = false;
        SendSerial("L");
   }
   await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(time));
}
```

Desse modo, está funcional. Mas eu gostaria de parar  de usar essa forma, desta vez, esperando a boolean `AlertOK` ficar `true` por exemplo.

Como se fosse (só uma ideia).
`await AlertOK == true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei como está implementado o método que chama o seu `StartNewTest`, porém você pode iniciar esse método em outra `thread`:

```
await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
{           
    await StartNewText(TestType);
});
```

Isso nos permite utilizar um `while` sem travar a `UI`:

```
case TestType.Lights:
{
    LightsOK = false;
    SendSerial("L");
    while(AlertOK == false) {}
    break;
}
```

Dessa forma você pode remover o `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(time))` e o seu método ficará ali dentro até que a variável `AlertOK` se torne `true`.